# R reduce chart size and remove gray background from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot some data. It works fine but I'd like to control the shape of the plotted area and to remove the grey background.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
ggplot(data.melted, aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous("Year") +
    scale_y_continuous("Fraction of papers") +
    scale_colour_discrete("Topics")
```

and this is the output it produces:[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ggplot(data.melted, aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous("Year") +
    scale_y_continuous("Fraction of papers") +
    scale_colour_discrete("Topics") + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

To specify dimensions when saving the plot. See `?ggsave` for additional options.

```
ggsave(p1, file = "plot.png", width = 5, height = 5)
```